# Where in history do Dryads come from?

Tags: ghost, mythology

I believe it's Norse, but can't seem to find a definite answer on the web. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

P.S: I heard once they are a sister-spirit of Banshees, is there any validity to this?

Comment: Google "dryad" - first link is WikiPedia - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dryad - how much searching around the web did you do?

Comment: Should perhaps be migrated to the [Mythology Stack Exchange](http://mythology.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dryads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dryad) are tree spirits from Greek mythology, a type of nymph.  [Banshees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banshee) are Irish and their wailing was said to foretell someone's death.  There's no connection between the two, except that they're both female.

Comment: "There's no connection between the two, except that they're both female."  - And supernatural spirits.